# Check my simplification of a fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

My test doesn't say much, just to "simplify"
$$\frac{6\pm\sqrt{8}}{2}$$

are my answers correct? If so, how do I write them properly?

$$3+2\sqrt2\\3-2\sqrt2$$

Comment: Why don't you edit your https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2828498/what-type-of-question-is-this-and-how-do-i-write-the-answer#2828498?

Comment: @Chinny84 Are you sure... :)

Comment: @gammatester: I simply deleted that question

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I write them properly?"?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire ha. That is rather embarrassing. Forgive me deleting the original post in shame!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made a slight mistake. Note that $$\frac{6\pm\sqrt8}2=\frac62\pm\frac{2\sqrt2}2=3\pm\sqrt2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{2}$ so you will get
$$\frac{6+2\sqrt{2}}{2}=3+\sqrt{2}$$